# how can i extract values inside quotes using regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

my text is

```
my_text = """ ["supra","value":"ddad7f1eada3c52c66cmh6ZG8tf-nLt1A596b7URouAxiT1JKph-ceBld-ISJapdG6bKrE1kvru158hLUBx2GdzABc6PHP-gNbnD8A=="}};</script> """
```

i want to extract the value which is

```
ddad7f1eada3c52c66cmh6ZG8tf-nLt1A596b7URouAxiT1JKph-ceBld-ISJapdG6bKrE1kvru158hLUBx2GdzABc6PHP-gNbnD8A==
```

i've tried this

```
extract_posted_data = re.search(r'(\"value\": \")(\w*)', my_text)
print (extract_posted_data.group(2))
```

and this is what i received

```
ddad7f1eada3c52c66cmh6ZG8tf
```

it isnt extracting the complete value

Thanks

Comment: Why are you searching for `posted_data` while the key is `value`?

Comment: Where is `posted_data` in your sample string `my_text`, your current code doesn't match anything when run as is with the string in `my_text`

Comment: Now change `\w*` to `[^"]*`

Comment: sorry my mistake i've updated the question please have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` is not included in `\w` (and also `=` is not included)
You'll need to use: `[\w=-]*` instead of `\w*`

Answer (score 0):

The regex that you're looking for is `r"\"value\":\"(\S+)\""` and the required string for you is available in `group(1)` of the match

Here's a live link to the regex with your test string to test. Regex101 also has code generators that you could use to generate the required python code and test.

https://regex101.com/r/p2N524/1

---

```
import re

regex = r"\"value\":\"(\S+)\""

test_str = "[\"supra\",\"value\":\"ddad7f1eada3c52c66cmh6ZG8tf-nLt1A596b7URouAxiT1JKph-ceBld-ISJapdG6bKrE1kvru158hLUBx2GdzABc6PHP-gNbnD8A==\"}};</script> "

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

#### Result

```
Match 1 was found at 9-123: "value":"ddad7f1eada3c52c66cmh6ZG8tf-nLt1A596b7URouAxiT1JKph-ceBld-ISJapdG6bKrE1kvru158hLUBx2GdzABc6PHP-gNbnD8A=="

Group 1 found at 18-122: ddad7f1eada3c52c66cmh6ZG8tf-nLt1A596b7URouAxiT1JKph-ceBld-ISJapdG6bKrE1kvru158hLUBx2GdzABc6PHP-gNbnD8A==
```